# Convert SP to Function in SQL for compare comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to write I function for compare comma separated values but I am not good in sql I got a stored pro 
This is working fine ...Can any one convert this SP in SQL function and return true or false ( now returning matching word)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CompareCSVInSQL 
 @str1   varchar(1500),
 @srt2  varchar(1500)
AS
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(1500) = @str1
DECLARE @v2 VARCHAR(1500) = @srt2
DECLARE @v1Words TABLE (word VARCHAR(1000))
DECLARE @v2Words TABLE (word VARCHAR(1000))

;WITH cteSplitV1 AS( 
SELECT CAST('<word>' + REPLACE(@v1,', ','</word><word>') + '</word>' AS XML) AS words) 
INSERT INTO @v1Words(word)
    SELECT word.x.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS [word]
    FROM cteSplitV1
    CROSS APPLY words.nodes('/word') AS word(x)

;WITH cteSplitV2 AS( 
SELECT CAST('<word>' + REPLACE(@v2,', ','</word><word>') + '</word>' AS XML) AS words) 
INSERT INTO @v2Words(word)
    SELECT word.x.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS [word]
    FROM cteSplitV2 
    CROSS APPLY words.nodes('/word') AS word(x)

SELECT *
FROM @v1Words v1
JOIN @v2Words v2
    ON v1.word = v2.word
END
GO



BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN
   DECLARE @srt1 varchar(1500)
   DECLARE @srt2 varchar(1500)
   set @srt1 = 'hello, world,one,two, yes'
   set @srt2 = 'jump,down, yes, one'
   SELECT dbo.CompareCSVInSQL(@srt1,@srt2) AS 'Matching'
END
ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```
CREATE FUNCTION CompareCSVInSQL
(
     @str1   varchar(1500),
 @srt2  varchar(1500)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @retValue BIT
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(1500) = @str1
DECLARE @v2 VARCHAR(1500) = @srt2
DECLARE @v1Words TABLE (word VARCHAR(1000))
DECLARE @v2Words TABLE (word VARCHAR(1000))

;WITH cteSplitV1 AS( 
SELECT CAST('<word>' + REPLACE(@v1,', ','</word><word>') + '</word>' AS XML) AS words) 
INSERT INTO @v1Words(word)
    SELECT word.x.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS [word]
    FROM cteSplitV1
    CROSS APPLY words.nodes('/word') AS word(x)

;WITH cteSplitV2 AS( 
SELECT CAST('<word>' + REPLACE(@v2,', ','</word><word>') + '</word>' AS XML) AS words) 
INSERT INTO @v2Words(word)
    SELECT word.x.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS [word]
    FROM cteSplitV2 
    CROSS APPLY words.nodes('/word') AS word(x)

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM @v1Words v1 JOIN @v2Words v2
                ON v1.word = v2.word)
BEGIN
    SET @retValue=1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @retValue=0
END
RETURN @retValue
END
```

This will returns true if there is matching words. Otherwise returns false

Comment: Hi Nithesh , Your funtion working fine but taking space in starting of word ...means ....'one' and 'one' is not matching but if I pass ' one' and ' one' then this will match ....how I can fix this ?